# Is there a way to avoid casts with generics when Type is used instead of Class<T>

Tags: java, generics

Say you have this code:

```
public <T> T deserialize(String input, Class<T> type) {
 return somethingThatRetunsAnInstanceOfT();
}
```

But, if the method accepted Type instead of Class, which is needed for proper JSON deserialization of generics, it would look like this:

```
public <T> T deserialize(String input, Type type) {
 return (T) somethingThatRetunsAnInstanceOfT();
}
```

Is there a way to avoid this ugly unchecked cast?

Comment: That's what I thought, just wanted to validate the assumption nothing can be done.... Feel free to make your comment an answer.

Comment: If your method signature doesn't involve `T`, you have no choice. With Generics there's no runtime magic that can happen behind the scenes, it's pure maths applied to static type signatures.

Comment: Well, hold on, I thought of something else. If the method you're calling is generic, you can explicitly provide the generic parameter, like: `EnclosingClass.<T>somethingThatReturnsAnInstanceOfT();`

Comment: @JornVernee That just pushes the unchecked cast one level deeper.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yeah, I guess so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your second example there is no way for compiler to identify value of `T`. In first example you give that information by putting generic class as parameter.

Generics are compile time construct only. From runtime you cannot get value of generics because of "type erasure".

Comment: *"From your second example there is no way for compiler to identify value of `T`"* This is not always true. Java can infer the type from the type of the variable where the result is assigned to. Like `MyType blub = deserialize(...)`. See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html#target_types

Answer (score 2):

If the class is needed runtime then you have to pass it explicitly. You cannot derive it in any from the generic type because this generic types are not available at runtime. This is called 'type erasure'. Generics only help with typing at compile time, not runtime.

Answer (score 1):

With your second signature, it would be possible to call

```
Type numberType = Integer.class.getGenericSuperclass(); // class java.lang.Number
String str = <String>deserialize("1", numberType);
```

and `somethingThatRetunsAnInstanceOfT` would presumably return a `Number`.

If you could achieve this without unchecked casts, it would be a bug in Java's type system.

Comment: Yup, I understand all this, was just hoping there's a way to make it type-safe that I'm missing